# Problem on conditional probability.

Tags: probability, statistics

A small brewery has three bottling machines. Machine $A$ produces $40\%$ of all the bottles, machines $B$ and $C$ produce $30\%$ each. *Five* percent of bottles filled by $A$, *four* percent of bottles filled by $B$, and *three* percent of bottles filled by $C$ are rejected for some reason.

**Question**: If a bottle is filled by $A$ or $B$, what is the probability that it is rejected?

**Hint**: Use the definition of conditional probability.
Find $P\{(A \cup B) \cap (rejected)\} = P\{A \cap (rejected)\} + P\{B \cap (rejected)\}$

**Answer**: $\dfrac{8}{175}$

---

First of all I tried plugging the numbers and got $0.4 \times 0.05 + 0.3 \times 0.04$ which is incorrect.

Secondly I don't understand how they got the formula from the hint.
I know that $P\{(A\cup B) \cap C\} = P(A \cup B) + P(C) - P\{(A\cup B)\cup C\}$ , however dont see why according to the author $P\{(A\cup B)\cup C\}=0$ in this formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asked to compute
$$
   \Pr\left(\text{rejected} \mid \left(A \cup B \right) \right) = \frac{ \Pr\left(\text{rejected} \cap \left(A \cup B \right) \right)}{\Pr\left( A \cup B \right)} =  \frac{ \Pr\left( \left(\text{rejected} \cap A \right) \cup \left(\text{rejected} \cap B \right) \right)}{\Pr\left( A \cup B \right)}
$$
Since a bottle can not be bottled by both machines, $A \cap B = \emptyset$, hence $\Pr\left(A \cup B \right) = \Pr(A) + \Pr(B)$, and likewise $$\Pr\left( \left(\text{rejected} \cap A \right) \cup \left(\text{rejected} \cap B \right) \right) = \Pr\left( \text{rejected} \cap A  \right) + \Pr\left( \text{rejected} \cap B  \right)$$
Hence
$$
 \Pr\left(\text{rejected} \mid \left(A \cup B \right) \right)  = \frac{\frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{20} + \frac{3}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{25}}{\frac{2}{5} + \frac{3}{10}} = \frac{8}{175}
$$